# Programmatically enter edit mode TextField

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, edit

I got a Editable textfield inside my uitableviewcell and want the user to be able to edit the content of the textfield. This works when the user clicks the small textfield but i want to enter that editing mode when clicking on the tableviewcell.

So in the tableview didselect row delegate I need to programmatically enter edit mode for that textfield but I can't find any method to do this. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Here is an example on how to use this method:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```